# Expected value of the sum of two n-sided dice rolls

Tags: probability, expected-value

given an n-sided die what is the expected value of the sum of two rolls. The answer I reached was n + 1, but I’m not sure if that’s correct.

Comment: What is $k$ here? Do you mean $n$ for both?

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: Oh sorry meant n + 1. My approach was to use linearity of expectation, so E(x1 + x2) = E(x1) + E(x2). I found that the expected value of a n-sided die is (n+1)/2, and so I summed those together to get n + 1.

Comment: @MagicKeko It seems right. I assume that the two dice are fair dice.

Comment: @callculus42 yes they are.

Comment: @callculus42 what would be the E(max{x1, x2}) because wouldn’t the E(x1) = E(x2)?

Comment: @MagicKeko Then all is fine. In your answer you should include how you have found $E(X_1)$. The max problem is a  different question.

Comment: @callculus42 ok thank you, and sorry this my first posting on here.

Comment: @MagicKeko No problem. You can ask a new question for the max-problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @MagicKeko . **Note** An answer should *never* just be the final result, but rather needs to include the path you took to obtain it.  In exams and assignments, for instance, this allows you to retain partial marks if you made an error along the way.  *Here* it allows responders find any such errors, and check your results without having to start from scratch.